# is it possible to have 2 data sets on single line chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js2

Preview:
I am using chart.js in Angular 7 application. I want to know, is it possible to have 2 data sets on single line chart.

Detail:
On my X-axis I have time related data and Y-axis contains numbers. Based on API response, (which returns time stamp and number) I can generate a line chart. But I want to have 2nd datasets on same line. 2nd data set related API response, gives me time stamp, so I want to use that time stamp to project point (maybe of different color) to show on single line.

```
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: this.getChartAxisData(),
      options: this.getChartOptions()
    });

getChartAxisData() {
    const first: any[] = this.listOne.map((data) => (new Date(data.date)));
    const firstArray: any[] = this.listOne.map((data) => data.number);
    const second: any[] = this.listTwo.map((data) => (new Date(data.date)));

    return {
      labels: first,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: firstArray
        }
      ]
    };
  }

getChartOptions() {

    return {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            max: this.endDate,
            min: this.startDate,
            displayFormats: {
              'millisecond': 'hh:mm A',
              'second': 'hh:mm A',
              'minute': 'hh:mm A',
              'hour': 'hh:mm A',
              'day': 'DD-MMM',
              'week': 'DD-MMM',
              'month': 'DD-MMM'
            }
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 800
          }
        }]
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: No can'nt use two dataset but you can use two object in dataset json.try https://jsfiddle.net/84rftogn/

Comment: Yea, but that doesn't fulfill our requirement. If one dataset I got, have to covert into single dataset from 2 lists.

Comment: try to create object and push into array ,i did same thing in my graphs where i want to show comapritive graphs